# Download multiple PDF at once

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have added a function where in when the user select multiple order then trigger the `Download PDF` button I added it will download PDF's with X number of PDF based from the number of selected orders. So basically when I select 3 PDF it should generate or download 3 PDF. But on my function it only download one pdf. How can I tell Magento 2 to download 3 pdf or more based from the number of selected items.

Below is my sample code

```
public function printPDF()
{
    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $page = $pdf->pages[0]; // this will get reference to the first page.
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $style->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0,0,0));
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
    $style->setFont($font,13);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $width = $page->getWidth();
    $hight = $page->getHeight();
    $x = 30;
    $pageTopalign = 850; 
    $this->y = 850 - 100; 

    $style->setFont($font,14);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y + 10, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y +70, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);

    $style->setFont($font,13);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Cutomer Details"), $x + 5, $this->y+50, 'UTF-8');
    $style->setFont($font,11);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Name : %1", "Test Meetanshi"), $x + 5, $this->y+33, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("Email : %1","test@meetanshi.com"), $x + 5, $this->y+16, 'UTF-8');

    $style->setFont($font,11);
    $page->setStyle($style);

    $page->drawText(__("PRODUCT NAME"), $x + 60, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("PRODUCT PRICE"), $x + 200, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("QTY"), $x + 310, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("SUB TOTAL"), $x + 440, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');

    $style->setFont($font,10);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $add = 9;

    $page->drawText("$12.00", $x + 210, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(10, $x + 330, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText("$120.00", $x + 470, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $pro = "TEST product";
    $page->drawText($pro, $x + 65, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');

    $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y + 10, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
    $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y - 100, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);

    $style->setFont($font,15);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Total : %1", "$50.00"), $x + 435, $this->y-85, 'UTF-8');

    $style->setFont($font,10);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Test Footer example"), ($page->getWidth()/2)-50, $this->y-200);

    $fileName = 'meetanshi.pdf';

    $this->fileFactory->create(
       $fileName,
       $pdf->render(),
       \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR, // this pdf will be saved in var directory with the name meetanshi.pdf
       'application/pdf'
    );
}
```

So in my `execute()` function I added this call

```
public function execute()
{
        $this->printPDF();
        $this->printPDF();
        $this->printPDF();
}
```

But it only download 1 PDF. How can I tell it to download multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below code to download multiple PDF at once.

public function execute()
{
    $labelsContent = [];
    $labelsContent[] = "pdf1";
    $labelsContent[] = "pdf2";
    $labelsContent[] = "pdf3";
    $outputPdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    foreach ($labelsContent as $content) {
        if (stripos($content, '%PDF-') !== false) {
                $pdfLabel = \Zend_Pdf::parse($content);
                foreach ($pdfLabel->pages as $page) {
                        $outputPdf->pages[] = clone $page;
                }
        } else {
                $page = $this->createPdfPage($content);
                if ($page) {
                        $outputPdf->pages[] = $page;
                }
        }
    }
    $fileName = 'meetanshi.pdf';
    $this->fileFactory->create(
       $fileName,
       $outputPdf->render(),
       \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
       'application/pdf'
    );
}

public function createPdfPage() 
{
  $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf(); //Create new PDF file
  $page = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
  $pdf->pages[] = $page;
  $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
  $style->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0,0,0));
  $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
  $style->setFont($font,13);
  $page->setStyle($style);
  $width = $page->getWidth();
  $hight = $page->getHeight();
  $x = 30;
  $pageTopalign = 850;
  $this->y = 850 - 100;

  $style->setFont($font,14);
  $page->setStyle($style);
  $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y + 10, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y +70, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);

  $style->setFont($font,13);
  $page->setStyle($style);
  $page->drawText(__("Cutomer Details"), $x + 5, $this->y+50, 'UTF-8');
  $style->setFont($font,11);
  $page->setStyle($style);
  $page->drawText(__("Name : %1", "Test Meetanshi"), $x + 5, $this->y+33, 'UTF-8');
  $page->drawText(__("Email : %1","test@meetanshi.com"), $x + 5, $this->y+16, 'UTF-8');

  $style->setFont($font,11);
  $page->setStyle($style);

  $page->drawText(__("PRODUCT NAME"), $x + 60, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
  $page->drawText(__("PRODUCT PRICE"), $x + 200, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
  $page->drawText(__("QTY"), $x + 310, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
  $page->drawText(__("SUB TOTAL"), $x + 440, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');

  $style->setFont($font,10);
  $page->setStyle($style);
  $add = 9;

  $page->drawText("$12.00", $x + 210, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
  $page->drawText(10, $x + 330, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
  $page->drawText("$120.00", $x + 470, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
  $pro = "TEST product";
  $page->drawText($pro, $x + 65, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');

  $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y + 10, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
  $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y - 100, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);

  $style->setFont($font,15);
  $page->setStyle($style);
  $page->drawText(__("Total : %1", "$50.00"), $x + 435, $this->y-85, 'UTF-8');

  $style->setFont($font,10);
  $page->setStyle($style);
  $page->drawText(__("Test Footer example"), ($page->getWidth()/2)-50, $this->y-200);
    return $page;
}
```